# Apache Axis and Map/Properties (aka, options) parameters

Tags: java, jax-ws, axis

I'm new to Apache Axis and Java-bases web services, so this question might be trivial.

I've a @WebMethod that should receive an arbitrary set of options as one of its parameters, things like outputFormat, showDetails, scoreThreeshold etc.

Ideally, I'd like that the client has not to specify null values for these options, if it is fine with the defaults (i.e., they're optional :-)). In regular Java this would just be a Properties or Map parameter. What is the best approach to do the same for a web service? I've read around that Axis/Jax-WS don't like Collection(s), apart from List and Set. So, what could I use instead?